# How to play video in loop in python gui

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I wrote this code to run the ad video in a gui but the problem I am having is that it only runs one time in the loop what I want is to keep running with the delay again and again in the loop. Does anybody know the solution for it?

```py
while True:

    root= Tk()
    root.geometry("1920x1080")
    root.configure(bg='black')

    l0 = Label(root, text='Welcome to Smart Shopping Mall', font="arial 45 bold", bg='#EE2668', fg='White', pady=25)
    l0.pack(fill=X)

    l1 = Label(root, text='How may I help You?', font="arial 35 ", fg='White', bg='Black')
    l1.pack(pady=100)

    def ad(label):
        time.sleep(5)
        global pop1
        pop1 = Toplevel(root)
        pop1.geometry('1920x1080+0+0')

        global videoplayer
        videoplayer = TkinterVideo(master=pop1, scaled=True, pre_load=False)
        videoplayer.load(r"ad.mp4")
        videoplayer.pack(expand=True, fill="both")
        videoplayer.play()
        pop1.overrideredirect(1)
        pop1.after(20000, lambda: pop1.destroy())


    video_label = Label(root, bg='black')
    video_label.pack()

    thread = threading.Thread(target=ad, args=(video_label,))
    thread.start()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: use `after` to repeatedly schedule a call to the `ad` function: `root.after(20000, ad, label)` in the `ad` function at the end

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to grap the Ended event?
I am a beginner myself but for my part it worked:

```
def loopVideo(event):
    videoplayer.play()
```

and then befor your root.mainloop():

```
videoplayer.bind('<<Ended>>', loopVideo)
root.mainloop()
```

for me the Documentation to tkVideoplayer helped a lot:
[Documentation tk Videoplayer](https://github.com/PaulleDemon/tkVideoPlayer/blob/master/Documentation.md)